# cakeEmail getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm trying to send an email in cakephp (no need to use ssl at the time), config seems fine but I keep getting the error above,  below is my smtp config:

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('test@mambihost.com' => 'Mambihost'),
    'host' => 'mail.mambihost.com ',
    'port' => 26,
    'timeout' => 100,
    'username' => 'test@mambihost.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

Why could this be happening? I'm running this in a wamp on my server which is inside a LAN. I can ping the host from the server with no problem but my app doesn't seem to reach it or something.

Could you help me please?

Comment: You have a space at the end of the host name.

Comment: Damn!! I can't believe that was it...I may be in need of some vacation If didn't noticed that . Thanks a lot Greg